# Shift and rolling average of not null values in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, aggregation

I am looking for a way to generate a moving window based on the average of the not null values in the past n days for each group.

For example, if the moving window size is 3, I want to generate the column *MovAvg*, based on the not null values in the *ct* column for each *Group* (i.e with a lagged effect).

```
Date    Group   ct      MovAvg
1/1/71  A   NaN NaN
2/1/71  A   1   NaN
3/1/71  A   NaN NaN
4/1/71  A   NaN 1
5/1/71  A   1   1
6/1/71  A   NaN 1
7/1/71  A   0   1
8/1/71  A   NaN 0.5
9/1/71  A   NaN 0
10/1/71 A   1   0
11/1/71 A   0   1
1/1/71  B   NaN NaN
2/1/71  B   1   NaN
3/1/71  B   NaN NaN
4/1/71  B   NaN 1
5/1/71  B   0   1
6/1/71  B   1   0
7/1/71  B   1   0.5
8/1/71  B   NaN 0.67
9/1/71  B   NaN 1
10/1/71 B   1   1
11/1/71 B   0   1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) with `min_periods=1` which needs at least one valid obeservation, so we can *somewhat* fix the issue with your `NaN`:

```
df['MovAvg'] = pd.concat([d['ct'].rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean().shift() for _, d in df.groupby('Group')])
```

---

```
print(df)
       Date Group   ct    MovAvg
0    1/1/71     A  NaN       NaN
1    2/1/71     A  1.0       NaN
2    3/1/71     A  NaN  1.000000
3    4/1/71     A  NaN  1.000000
4    5/1/71     A  1.0  1.000000
5    6/1/71     A  NaN  1.000000
6    7/1/71     A  0.0  1.000000
7    8/1/71     A  NaN  0.500000
8    9/1/71     A  NaN  0.000000
9   10/1/71     A  1.0  0.000000
10  11/1/71     A  0.0  1.000000
11   1/1/71     B  NaN       NaN
12   2/1/71     B  1.0       NaN
13   3/1/71     B  NaN  1.000000
14   4/1/71     B  NaN  1.000000
15   5/1/71     B  0.0  1.000000
16   6/1/71     B  1.0  0.000000
17   7/1/71     B  1.0  0.500000
18   8/1/71     B  NaN  0.666667
19   9/1/71     B  NaN  1.000000
20  10/1/71     B  1.0  1.000000
21  11/1/71     B  0.0  1.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  df['MovAvg'] = df['ct'].groupby(df['Group']).rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean().shift()
```

Comment: `df['ct'].groupby(df['Group'])` :  This groups the column ct based on column 'Group'
`rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean()`: for the groups created in first part, this will calulate rolling mean for 3 periods. `min_period = 1` will calculate mean if at least one row is not NaN.
`shift()`  :  this will shift your rolling means by one time period down.

Comment: OK--can you edit your post to include this information? Do you have anything else to say about `rolling`, `mean` and `shift`? Take a look at the other answer if you're not sure how to explain your code.